# How can I set repeating alarm while idle with Alarm Manager (Kotlin - Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

val intent = Intent(activity?.applicationContext, ReminderNotificationService::class.java)
val title = notificationTitle
val message = "$notificationMessage ${binding.etBillName.text.toString().trim()}"
intent.putExtra(notificationTitleExtra, title)
intent.putExtra(notificationMessageExtra, message)

val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
context,
REMINDER_NOTIFICATION_ID,
intent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

```
    val alarmManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

    val updateYear = Calendar.getInstance()
    updateYear.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()

    val year = updateYear.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    updateYear.set(Calendar.YEAR, year + 1)

    //setExactAndAllowWhileIdle
    //setInexactRepeating
    alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        getTime(),
        pendingIntent
    )
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You should schedule another exact alarm when you Broadcast receiver's onReceive gets called from previous alarm's PendingIntent.

Meanwhile, be careful while scheduling exact alarm with Android 12 restrictions.

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#exact

Comment: Thank you. But will this hold up if the device is restarted?

Comment: Alarms will be cancelled when device reboot. You can reactivate when ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast receives.Please refer [link](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#boot)